# Unexpected value printed when trying to print sorted array

Tags: java, sorting

Here is my code. Can someone help me with this error?

```
public class ExcahngeSort {

    public double[] ExSort(double[] gangnam,int size)
    { double temp;

        for(int outrloop=1;outrloop<size;outrloop++)
        {

            for (int innrloop=0;innrloop<size-outrloop;innrloop++)
            {

                if(gangnam[innrloop]>gangnam[innrloop+1])
                {
                     temp=gangnam[innrloop];
                    gangnam[innrloop]=gangnam[innrloop+1];
                    gangnam[innrloop+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }   
        return gangnam;
    }
}
```

I get an unexpected value `[D@360be0`printed. I don't know what this means.

Here is my main method:

```
public class BsortSimulate {
    public static void main (String args []){

        //BSort bs = new BSort();
        ExcahngeSort es = new ExcahngeSort();
        double gangnam [] = {12,24};

        System.out.println(es.ExSort(gangnam, 2));

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the array incorrectly, use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5b%5d%29) utility method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(es.ExSort(gangnam, 2)));
```

Arrays in Java do not override `toString()`, as opposed to most `List` implementations.

Comment: but when i make the change as u said i dont get any output .i import the import java.util.Arrays; package also and im a newbie please help me with this. i think it must be an error in my code not in the array

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(es.ExSort(gangnam, 2)));
```

Comment: @ChawBawwa What is it printing?

Comment: i have tried it and its working

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. You are trying to print array object. You can't override toString() for arrays in Java.

Your print statement should be like below:

Example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(es.ExSort(gangnam, 2)));
```